# Rails devise with scope fails with InvalidAuthenticityToken

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

We are using Rails 4.2.1 and the latest version of Devise (3.4.1) although I believe the same error occurs with other versions.

Ever since we added scope to routes.rb:

```
scope '/admin' do

  root to: "places#index"

  devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: "users/registrations" }

...
```

Devise fails to sign in or sign out with the following error:

```
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken at /admin/users/sign_out.
```

Everything works perfectly fine as long as we remove the scope.

We tried using custom routes with devise but nothing helped.

---

registrations_controller.rb

---

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up).push(:first_name, :last_name, :organization)
  end
end
```

Comment: Sei, could you share your custom users/registrations_controller.rb file?
This may help in finding the issue.

Comment: even if we remove users/registrations_controller.rb from the routing file we still get the same error. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to define your scope for devise as following:

```
devise_for :users 
devise_scope :user do
  scope '/admin' do
    get "/your_route" ...
  end
end
```

And for the rest of the routes apply "/admin" scope separately.